# JPA: Foreign key in embeddable class

Tags: jpa

I have the following situation to solve, but could not get it work (tried Hibernate and EclipseLink):

```
Table_1:
    Column_A is Primary Key
    ... some other columns do follow
```

.

```
Table_2:
Column_x is Primary Key and is Foreign Key to Table_1.Column_A
Column_y is Primary Key and is Foreign Key to Table_1.Column_A
Column_z is Primary Key
```

Thus, table 2 has a composite primary key.

I tried to realize it the following way:

```
class Table_1 {
  @Id int Column_A;
}
```

.

```
class Table_2 {
  @EmbeddedId PK key;

  @Embeddable class PK {
    @OneToOne(targetEntity=Table_1.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="Column_x",referencedColumnName="Column_A")
    int Column_x;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity=Table_1.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="Column_y",referencedColumnName="Column_A")
    int Column_y;

    int Column_z;

    public boolean equals(Object O) { ... }
    public int hashCode() { ... } 
  }
}
```

However, when I run, I get the hint from EclipseLink that in @Embeddable I may only use "basic" annotations. Thus, my question is how to solve the above drawn scenario?

I do not have access to the source code of class Table_1, but must use it as it is. Also, it will be very likely that there may be more classes / tables establishing foreign keys to Table_1.

Answer (score 1):

Use an @IdClass.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#JPA_2.0

```
@IdClass(PK.class)
class Table_2 {
    @Id
    @OneToOne(targetEntity=Table_1.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="Column_x",referencedColumnName="Column_A")
    Table_1 Column_x;

    @Id
    @OneToOne(targetEntity=Table_1.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="Column_y",referencedColumnName="Column_A")
    Table_1 Column_y;

    @Id
    int Column_z;

    public boolean equals(Object O) { ... }
    public int hashCode() { ... } 
  }
}

class PK {
    int Column_x;
    int Column_y;
    int Column_z;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right to use @EmbeddedId (and not @IdClass, which is more for generated IDs than foreign keys). I think your problem is that you're declaring those FKs as integers when they should actually be typed to the Table_1 or Table_2 class.